# Dropdown visibility Depend upon First dropdown value selection flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I create a 2 dropdown then second dropdown visibility depend upon first dropdown. here I add first dropdown for type selection then select type and visible second dropdown. which is (month or quarter or year). Here not only two but total 4 dropdown second dropdown depend upon first so display only two dropdown. which one is selected is show like., month selected then month dropdown display..

here problem about when you click the first dropdown, the visibility or ui doesnt change..

here first dropdown for type selection like: month, quarter and year then second dropdown show which value is selected from first dropdown. if first dropdown select quarter then quarter dropdown show and another two hidden. I am facing realtime statemanagement issue. if hotreload its display as selected dropdown.

```
final ReportProvider _reportprovider = context.read<ReportProvider>();

Container(                          
width: 300.0,
margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 10, 0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline( //first dropdown for select type
      child: DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
        value: _reportprovider.selected_type,
        isExpanded: true,
        items: _reportprovider.type.map((items) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
            value: items.first,
            child: Text(items.last.toString()),
          );
        }).toList(),
        hint: Text("Select Type"),
        //month[0],
        onChanged: (value) {
          _reportprovider.onchanged(value!);
        },
      ),
    );
),
```

```
//this three dropdown visibility depend upon first dropdown selection
Column(
                        children: [
                          Visibility(
                            visible: _reportprovider.monthly,
                            child: Container(
                                width: 320.0,
                                margin:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 10, 0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                child: selectmonthlist()), //month list dropdown show/hide with type selection
                          ),
                          Visibility(
                            visible: _reportprovider.quarterly,
                            child: Container(
                                width: 320.0,
                                margin:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 10, 0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                child: selectquarter()),//quarter list dropdown show/hide with type selection
                          ),
                          Visibility(
                            visible: _reportprovider.yearly,
                            child: Container(
                                width: 320.0,
                                margin:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 10, 0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                child: selectyearly()),//year list dropdown show/hide with type selection
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

```
//provider

class ReportProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int selected_type = 0;
  bool monthly = true;
  bool quarterly = true;
  bool yearly = true;

  bool getmonthly() => monthly;
  bool getquarterly() => quarterly;
  bool getyearly() => yearly;

  onchanged(int value) async {
    if (value == 0) {
      monthly = true;
      quarterly = false;
      yearly = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } else if (value == 1) {
      monthly = false;
      quarterly = true;
      yearly = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } else if (value == 2) {
      monthly = false;
      quarterly = false;
      yearly = true;
      notifyListeners();
    }
    selected_type = value;
    prefs.setInt('type', value);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Can you include sample data and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I can understand your problem to some degree. If you can confirm the problem, I can share a better solution. Your problem is you have 4 dropdown widgets, each dropdown widget depends on the previous dropdown. I am not speaking about the items in each dropdown just yet. Please let me know if I understood your issue correctly

Comment: Does this solves your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323767/multiple-dependent-dropdown-in-flutter

Comment: Its give value from first dropdown but i need visibility of three dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

is the problem about when you click the first dropdown, the visibility or ui doesnt change?

you can add setstate to your code, so it will render the build(..) again

Comment: setstate not working then i use provider, but its also not works...